# Trying to make sense of Windows timestamps....

Tags: windows, timestamp, computer-forensics

I'm in a situation that involves the manual reconstruction of raw data, to include MFT records and other Windows artifacts. I understand that timestamps in MFT records are 64-bit integers, big endian, and are calculated by the number of 100 nanosecond intervals since 01/01/1601 00:00:00 UTC. I am also familiar with Windows email header timestamps, which consist of two 32-bit values that combine to form a single 64-bit value, also calculated by the number of 100 nanosecond intervals since 01/01/1601 00:00:00 UTC.

But there are other Windows timestamps with different epochs, such as SQL Server timestamps, which I believe use a date in the 1800's. I cannot find much documentation on all of this. What timestamps are used in Windows other than the two listed above? How do you break them down?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/05/54806.aspx).

Comment: That is helpful, thanks. Do you know of any good Mac time references, for things other than Mac Absolute Time?

Comment: I never worked on Mac, so I can't give you any useful advice. :(

Comment: Link to blog post referenced in the first comment is broken but I think it is now available at: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030905-02/?p=42653

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code for decoding Windows timestamps:

```
static string microsoftDateToISODate(const uint64_t &time) {
/**
 * See comment above for more information on
 * SECONDS_BETWEEN_WIN32_EPOCH_AND_UNIX_EPOCH 
 *
 * Convert UNIX time_t to ISO8601 format
 */
time_t tmp = (time / ONE_HUNDRED_NANO_SEC_TO_SECONDS)
    - SECONDS_BETWEEN_WIN32_EPOCH_AND_UNIX_EPOCH;

struct tm time_tm;
gmtime_r(&tmp, &time_tm);
char buf[256];
strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", &time_tm);
return string(buf);
}
```

And your reference for Mac timestamps is:

- [Apple Mac and Unix timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864798/apple-mac-and-unix-timestamps)
- http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1398/_index.html

Comment: Thanks for the Mac links, if you notice, I wrote the Stack Overflow reference you linked to ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with this code really. My goal is to understand how the timestamps work. I don't really understand what I'm looking at in your code. The eventual goal is to finish this wiki: http://code.google.com/p/opensourceforensics/wiki/TimestampConversion and then write a multi-platform tool in python that decodes all of these timestamps. So it is imperative I understand the math behind them and not just rely on system functions for various languages to do this. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it. But any help understanding all of these formats would be extremely helpful also.

Comment: I understand the ones in my question, my goal is to understand additional types of Windows timestamps such as the ones used in SQL Server.

Comment: Where are you encountering the other timestamps?

Comment: I am carving/reconstructing data out of unallocated space on Windows computers. I've noticed that SQL uses DB/DT_TIMESTAMP (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx) which is mostly human-readable, but what about DOS, CLR System time, etc.? Looking for explanations of multiple types of timestamps that can be encountered in Windows OS in various places. Primarily ones I am not currently aware of.