# Apple Mac and Unix timestamps

Tags: macos, timestamp, computer-forensics

I know that the primary timestamp on Apple systems is the CF Absolute Time value (also called Mac Absolute Time), which is a 32-bit integer calculated by the number of seconds since 01/01/2001 00:00:00 UTC. For example, 219216022 when decoded is Thu, 13 December 2007 05:20:22 UTC.

Are there any other timestamps used on Mac/Unix systems (other than the default Unix timestamp which is a 32-bit integer calculated in seconds since 01/01/1970 00:00:00 UTC)?

Comment: ITYM "Mach Absolute Time" or `mach_absolute_time()`, not "Mac Absolute Time".

Comment: See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1398/_index.html

Comment: Here's what I was working on when I wrote this question, FYI: http://web.archive.org/web/20120620182552/http://code.google.com/p/opensourceforensics/wiki/TimestampConversion (unfortunately it is no longer up, I made the mistake of sharing an instance of Google Code with someone who wiped it out, luckily Wayback Machine still has it).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As pointed out by @MarcusJ, the the [AIFF Specification](http://www.muratnkonar.com/aiff/) has a 32-bit binary timestamp that on the Amiga is the number of seconds since January 1, 1978, and on the Mac is the number of seconds since January 1, 1904.

Comment: That's not true. In the AIFF specification, they store date fields as the number of seconds since January 1, 1904.

Answer (score 1):

The NSDate object has timeIntervalSince1970, but that's based off the mach time.  Meaning `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]-NSTimeIntervalSince1970` is equal to `[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];`