# How to get the real calendar microseconds time (epoch since 1970) in Mac OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, c++14, c++-chrono

Kindly go through below Qn for the context:
[Why does clang++/g++ not giving correct microseconds output for chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() in Mac OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45882606/514235)

As already discussed in above thread, I intend to get `microseconds` time since 1970.
Now using `chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()` works well in popular platforms except OSX & possibly iOS. In [our] Mac systems, the microseconds time is generated since the system restart & not since 1970.

Is there any portable [or Mac specific] way to get the time since 1970, with the precision of `microseconds`?
Solution specific to Qt are also welcome.

Comment: Does [`gettimeofday`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html) not work correctly?

Comment: As there are currently 2 close votes on this question, I hereby post my intent to vote to reopen this question should it be closed.  The current rationale for closing: Not clear what is being asked, is not true for me.  It is perfectly clear to me what is being asked, and I have provided an answer.

Comment: @dbush, I didn't use that function as it as part of "sys/" filesystem, which may not be portable in Windows. Besides, I wanted to use the C++11 facility.

Comment: Of the three standard clocks, only `system_clock` is guaranteed to give you wall-clock time.  `steady_clock` is "[not related to wall clock time](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock)," and `high_resolution_clock` "[may be an alias of ... `steady_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock)."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On macOS this is how you can get microseconds since 1970-01-01 UTC (excluding leap seconds):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    std::cout << std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count() << "us\n";
}
```

This just output for me:

```
1503715928742714us
```

This isn't quite portable. Though all platform's `system_clock`s do measure time since 1970-01-01 UTC (not specified but de facto standard), they do so with differing precisions.  Only macOS uses microseconds.  To portably output microseconds:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
std::cout << time_point_cast<microseconds>(system_clock::now()).time_since_epoch().count() << "us\n";
```

If you would like to do this operation while exploring what precision other platforms measure this time with, you can use [Howard Hinnant's date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) to very easily do this:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::cout << system_clock::now().time_since_epoch() << '\n';
}
```

For me this just output:

```
1503716308206361µs
```

On gcc platforms the units would be `ns`.  And on Windows the units would be `[1/10000000]s`, which is 1/10 of a µs or 100ns.

---

About `chrono::high_resolution_clock`:

The standard specifies that `high_resolution_clock` may be a type alias for `system_clock` or `steady_clock`, or it may be a separate type.  On macOS and Windows, `high_resolution_clock` is a typedef for `steady_clock`.  On gcc `high_resolution_clock` is a typedef for `system_clock`.  So you can't depend on the type or behavior of `high_resolution_clock`.  I don't recommend its use.

---

About `chrono::steady_clock`:

`steady_clock` is like a stopwatch.  It is great for timing how long something takes.  But it can't tell you the time of day.  It has no relationship whatsoever to a human calendar on any platform.  On macOS `steady_clock` it is a count of nanoseconds since the computer booted.

For a video tutorial about the current different `std::chrono` clocks, please see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M

---

**Only** `system_clock` counts time since the [Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (de facto standard, not official).  There is a [proposal under consideration](https://wg21.link/p0355) to make this official, and to add these additional clocks:

[`utc_clock`](https://wg21.link/p0355#time.clock.utc): Like `system_clock` but includes leap seconds.

[`tai_clock`](https://wg21.link/p0355#time.clock.tai): Measures physical seconds since 1958-01-01 00:00:00.  Moves a second ahead of `utc_clock` every time there is a leap second.  *All* minutes have 60 seconds.

[`gps_clock`](https://wg21.link/p0355#time.clock.gps):  Like `tai_clock` but measures time since the first Sunday of January 1980 00:00:00 UTC.

[`file_clock`](https://wg21.link/p0355#time.clock.file):  This is proposed to be the clock that the C++17 filesystem library is based on.  It isn't specified, but all known implementations relate this somehow to the civil calendar.

Comment: The solution using `time_point_cast<>` works perfectly for me in Mac. I can see the difference of output :-) `now = 1809778988
now = 1503723494460784`.

Comment: Excellent!  Glad I could help.